# How do I point a domain registered with Dynadot to a subdirectory of my Godaddy Hosting?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, godaddy, shared-hosting

I have a domain registered with Dynadot and I'd like to use my GoDaddy hosting to build the site to save having to pay out for more hosting. I'd need to set it up on a subdomain e.g. subdomain.example.com, how do I point my Dynadot domain to that subdirectory?

Comment: Domains don't work like that, they point at servers, not folders, your GoDaddy hosting is then responsible for mapping `/sub-folder/` to the domain, this is done in what's called a virtual host file. You need to ensure your hosting account supports multiple domains, if it does, then within control panel of GoDaddy you need to add an 'add-on' domain. Then, on your DOMAIN host change the nameservers to GoDaddys (provided to you by GoDaddy) or point the A record to IP address at GoDaddy,

Comment: What type of Godaddy hosting do you have?  Do you have Linux cPanel hosting?  If so, this article could help: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-addon-domains-to-host-multiple-websites-8877

Comment: With that said, as a paying customer, your entitled to free technical support provided by GoDaddy, they will be able to talk you through the process, including giving you the vital information users on Pro Webmasters can't give you, like the IP address at GoDaddy (they have thousands) or the name servers.

Comment: For changing the nameservers at Dyna, see https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/set-name-servers

Comment: And the name servers you should be able to get from: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/find-my-godaddy-nameservers-12318 just click the right hosting package, alternatively, just talk to them, fast and easy!